# adding number axis

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\begin{figure} 
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}

 \draw[>=latex, ->] (-1,0) -- (7,0) node[right] {$E$};
  \draw[>=latex, ->] (0,-1) -- (0,7) node[above] {$V$};

\draw[dashed] (-1, 6) parabola bend (3,1) (6,5);

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{\textit{V} and \textit{E} along a critical line  }
\end{figure}
```

once I have designed the parabola how can I add the label V1,,V5 and E1...E5 with the relative straight line as in the figure[image]

Comment: By now you have received several answers, and should hence know that codes are supposed to start with `\documentclas` and end with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I know I m writing my master thesis \documentclas and end with \end{document} its just written

Comment: Everybody is in the same situation. But you are forcing others to guess which document class you're using and to type these things. Why can't you do that for those who spend their time looking at *your* questions?

Comment: you are right sorry I ll never do it again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two possibilities. One is using `parabola bend` and `intersections` and the other one a real parabola (function).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure} 
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw[-latex] (-1,0) -- (7,0) node[right] {$E$};
 \draw[-latex] (0,-1) -- (0,7) node[above] {$V$};
 \draw[dashed,name path=parabola] (-1, 6) parabola bend (3,1) (6,5);
 \foreach [count=\Y starting from 0] \X in {4,4.4,4.8,5.4}
 {\path[name path=v-\Y] (\X,0) -- ++ (0,7);
 \draw[thin,name intersections={of=parabola and v-\Y,by=i-\Y}]
 (\X,0) node[below]{$E_{\Y}$} -- (i-\Y) -- (0,0 |- i-\Y) node[left]{$V_{\Y}$}; }
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{$V$ and $E$ along a critical line using intersections.}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={f(\x)=0.3*(\x-3)*(\x-3)+1;}]
 \draw[-latex] (-1,0) -- (7,0) node[right] {$E$};
 \draw[-latex] (0,-1) -- (0,7) node[above] {$V$};
 \draw[dashed] plot[domain=-1:6,samples=36] ({\x},{f(\x)});
 \foreach [count=\Y starting from 0] \X in {4,4.4,4.8,5.4}
 {
 \draw[thin]
 (\X,0) node[below]{$E_{\Y}$} -- (\X,{f(\X)}) -- (0,{f(\X)})node[left]{$V_{\Y}$}; }
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{$V$ and $E$ along a critical line using a function.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]